# How can I get the If-Match header as a string using HttpRequestHeader

Tags: c#, header

I'm building a http request in my c# client and and want to append an `If-Match` header. To get that If-Match header, I'm using this object which comes from `System.Net`:

```
var headerkey = HttpRequestHeader.IfMatch.ToString();
```

I would expect calling toString on this to output: `If-Match` however, instead I'm getting `IfMatch` which is not a valid http header. Is there a way I can get the correct value without hardcoding a string in my code that looks like this:

```
const string ifMatch = "If-Match";
```

Comment: Why do you not use the class WebHeaderCollection to construct the headers? It uses the enumeration HttpRequestHeader. The translation between the enum and the actual header name is in a private system library, that you cannot access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below, and it will generate the headers that you need based on those enums, instead of performing a ToString on an enum

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
var headers = request.Headers;
headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.IfMatch, "NameHere")
```